# Can't set web part to auto adjust height

Tags: web-part, web-part-page, web-part-property

I have an Excel Web Part on a web part page that has a fixed height of 400 pixels. Every time I try to set the height to auto adjust, the setting won't take hold. The next time I go to edit the web part's properties it has reverted to the fixed height of 400px again.

I can set a different fixed height and that setting will stick, but whenever I try to set it to auto, it reverts back to 400.

Why is it doing this? How can I get the web part to auto adjust its height?

Answer (score 1):

if that is the case, please write some CSS to the web part div on the page through CEWP with !important attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I'm not yet very experienced with using CSS in this way. Could you provide an example of the CSS that would do this?

Also, I would like to know what the actual cause of this issue is, and if there is a way to truly fix it - this is more of a workaround. I'd prefer a solution that's more OOTB, if one exists.